# Using \mathtt{A} and the Package \usepackage{MnSymbol}

Tags: math-mode, errors, math-operators

How can you use the symbol  `\mathtt{A}` and  the Package `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`?

My code begin with

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{shuffle}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[french,linesnumbered,algoruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{pst-node,pstricks,multido,pst-plot,pst-text,pst-3d}%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```

I get these warnings and errors

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.656 \mathtt B
_{n,k}(P_1,\dots,P_m,\dots)=\mathfrak B_{n,k}[\a^{( P)}_{\Ph...
Your command was ignored.
```

Comment: Do you *really* need `MnSymbol`? It produces symbols with shapes clashing with Latin Modern fonts. And it's hungry with respect to math alphabets, as you discovered.

Comment: A workaround is to use `\textnormal{\texttt{B}}` instead of `\mathtt[B}`. Note that you allocate a math group (there are only 16 of them) for `stmaryrd` and `shuffle`.

Comment: Weird, I compiled using this preamble with no problem.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but there's no need to load `amsmath` or `amssymb` twice.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{shuffle}

\begin{document}
$\mathbf{A}\mathit{A}\mathsf{A}\mathbb{A}\mathtt{A}$
\end{document}
```

where only the math font related packages have been kept.

One has to know that each `\DeclareSymbolFont` declaration uses up one of the available 16 math groups. The default setup allocates groups from 0 to 3, then `amssymb` allocates other two; four are used by `MnSymbol`, one by `stmaryrd` and one by `shuffle`. A total of twelve, so only three additional math alphabets can be used in the document.

Some `\mathX` command don't really use a new math alphabet, which is the case for `\mathbb` (it shares a math group with those defined by `amssymb`) but not of `\mathfrak` nor `\mathbf` and others. Math alphabets (loaded with `\DeclareMathAlphabet`) only allocate a math group at point of usage, so in the code above the first four instructions exhaust the available groups and `\mathtt` is not able to find a place for allocating a group.

You can avoid wasting math groups with various techniques. For instance, the `shuffle` package can be avoided by defining the symbols it provides in a different way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%\usepackage{shuffle}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\shuffle}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\usefont{U}{shuffle}{m}{n}\symbol{"001}}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cshuffle}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\usefont{U}{shuffle}{m}{n}\symbol{"002}}}%
}


\begin{document}
$x\shuffle y\cshuffle z_{x\shuffle y\cshuffle z}$

$\mathbf{A}\mathit{A}\mathsf{A}\mathfrak{A}\mathtt{A}$
\end{document}
```

and now `\mathtt` can be used. This doesn't guarantee that math groups will not be used up again. For the most rarely used commands of the set, you can define (slower) substitutes; for instance, here's the preamble code for not allocating a math group with `\mathtt`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\mathtt}[1]{%
    \text{\normalfont\ttfamily #1}%
  }%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got some redundant packages in there which are using up math family slots (of which there are only 16 total). (Note that `amsart` also loads the `amsfonts` package which uses up several more for `\mathfrak`, `\mathbb`, etc.).

I am not sure you really need the MnSymbol package. If I am not wrong it is enough to have the `amssymb` package.

I found an example on the internet:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amscd, MnSymbol,mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbm}{U}{bbm}{m}{n}% from bbm.sty
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf A
\mathcal A
\mathfrak A
\mathscr A
\mathsf A
\mathbb A
\mathbbm a
\]
\end{document}
```

Let me know if it compiles.